# Scala list append a class in list and retrieve item

Tags: list, scala

new to scala so missing basic of list.

I'm trying to make a list of following class

```
  case class Person (val name: String, val age:Int, val email: String)
```

How do I make a list immutable list of Person class?

I tried:-

```
val list: List[Person] = List(Person("",0,"")) // compilation ok
list.::(person) // compile ok
```

But when I  check size it is 1. It should be 2. Also I don't see the added person in the list.

Please let me know how do I make list of Person class, inset new person and then retrieve person if either age or name or email or by index as well.

Please don't refer me to api doc http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List

It is hard to understand :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Soumya Simanta said, you have an immutable list, so you have to assign the `List` returned by the `::` operator to a new `val`. By the way you can use following notation

```
val list2 = person :: list
```

which is equivalent to

```
val list2 = list.::(person)
```

To get the information of your `Person` instances you can use the following line:

```
list2 foreach { p: Person => println(p.email) }
```

`foreach` is a method of `List`. It applies a function (e.g. `{ p: Person => println(p.email) }`) to all elements of the list.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
   val list2 = list.::(person)
```

Remember `list` is immutable. 
`list2` should have size 2.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping in mind immutable lists as aforementioned, for

```
case class Person (val name: String = "", 
                   val age:Int = 0, 
                   val email: String = "")
```

(note you can set construction defaults to each field) and

```
val list: List[Person] = List(Person("",0,"")) // compilation ok
```

we can construct a second `List[Person]` also with the `List` concatenation operator `++` as follows,

```
val list2 = list ++ List(Person(age=1)) 
list2: List(Person(,0,), Person(,1,))
```

To retrive a `Person` by a given criterium, for instance in this example, by `age`, consider `collect` as follows,

```
val list3 = list2.collect { case p@Person(_, age, _) if age == 1 => p }
List[Person] = List(Person(,1,))
```

Here we extract the field of interest, `age`, and check for a condition (whether it equates to 1), thus we select those entries in `list2` that hold the condition; to deliver such entries, we use a bind `p` on each `Person` instance; perhaps more canonical (and unnecessarily repetitive) approach would be

```
val list3 = list2.collect { 
  case Person(name, age, email) if age == 1 => Person(name, age, email) }
```

A similar approach relies in `filter` as follows,

```
list2.filter(p => p.age == 1)
```

And with a for comprehension, like this

```
for ( p@Person(n, a, e) <- list2  if a == 1 ) yield p
```

A more elaborated approach to defining a selection over a list of entries includes the definition of a method that takes a predicate as argument and evaluates it against each entry; in addition this can be encapsulated in an implicit class for ease of use; thus consider this example,

```
implicit class PersonsOps( val persons: List[Person] ) extends AnyVal {
  def select(pred: Person => Boolean) = persons.filter(pred)
}
```

and so we can define an anonymous function in the call to `byAge`, namely `(x: Person) => x.age == 1`; hence

```
list2.select( (x: Person) => x.age == 1 )
```

or equivalently

```
list2.select( _.age == 1 )
```

Note in this illustrative example `select` and `filter` are equivalent or interchangeable, yet `select` may be enriched/extended with additional requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
list.::(person)
```

retrieves a new list, containing both elements: the old and the new. However, the operation does not change your list called list. Try this way:

```
var list: List[Person] = List(Person("",0,"")) // compilation ok
list = list.::(person) // compile ok
```

Comment: That wouldn't compile, as you can't reassign a `val`. A `var` would work, though it's still bad style.